# Defean Bot when join voice channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have found this snippet of code but I don't know how I can use it in my `index.js`. Any ideas?

```
voiceChannel.join()
  .then(connection => {
      connection.voice.setSelfDeaf(true);
  });
```

Comment: Welcome, my advice just try to find any existing discord bot github repository.

Comment: Hi thanks, i found this snippet on stackoverflow.. i don't know how i can use it :/

Comment: that's why I suggested examining any existing bot sample, the official documentation usually leaves an online code sample. You send a tweet to me if you can't found that. Since your q not quite clear.

Comment: I just want the bot to defean itself when join a voice channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a reply to your comment, the following code will defean your bot everytime it joins a voice channel.

```js
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState) => {
    if (!newVoiceState.channel) {return false}; // The bot disconnected.
    if (newVoiceState.id == client.user.id) { // Checking if it is the bot.
        newVoiceState.setSelfDeaf(true); // Setting self defean to true.
    };
});
```

To make your bot join a voice channel:

```js
// Getting the channel.
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("722944525986955386");
// Joining the channel.
channel.join();
```